# Modify something in a Scala tree

Tags: scala, tree-traversal, case-class

I have a tree data structure in Scala built using case classes (it is of an AST, but that is irrelevant to the question). To modify the tree, I use a recursive function with destructs and reconstructs every case class in the whole tree:

```
def update(tree: Tree, id: String, val: Int): Tree = {
  tree match {
    case NodeType1(childs) =>
      NodeType1(childs.map(update(_, id, val)))
    case NodeType2(a, childs) =>
      NodeType2(a, childs.map(update(_, id, val))
    case NodeType3(a, b, childs) =>
      NodeType3(a, b, childs.map(update(_, id, val))
    ...  
    case Leaf(`id`, oldVal) =>
      Leaf(id, val)
  }
}
```

All the nodes in the tree are just "drive through" except for the Leaf node with the correct id, which is updated. I have about 27 different node types so the match block gets very large.

Can this type of matching code be expressed in a more succinct way? I don't care that the code doesn't modify the tree in place I just want it to get shorter.

Answer (score 1):

This idiom - applying a function (in your case, replacing values for a particular `id`) to the values inside a structure - can be represented by a [Functor](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/functor.html) in Cats:

```
trait Functor[F[_]] {
  def map[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]
}
```

You can implement the `map` function for your tree once like this:

```
implicit val functorForTree: Functor[Tree] = new Functor[Tree] {
  def map[A, B](t: Tree[A])(f: A => B): Tree[B] = t match {
    case NodeType1(childs)    => NodeType1(childs.map(_.map(f))
    case NodeType2(a, childs) => NodeType2(a, childs.map(_.map(f))
    ...
    case LeafNode(a)          => LeafNode(f(a))
  }
```

Note that to achieve this, the `Tree` must be parametrized by the leaf type, in your case `Leaf(id, val)`, i.e. instead of

```
sealed trait Tree
case class NodeType1(childs: List[Tree]) extends Tree
case class Leaf(id, val) extends Tree
```

you would need

```
sealed trait Tree[Leaf]
case class NodeType1[Leaf](childs: List[Tree[Leaf]]) extends Tree[Leaf]
case class NodeType2[Leaf](a: String, childs: List[Tree[Leaf]]) extends Tree[Leaf]
...
case class LeafNode[Leaf](leaf: Leaf) extends Tree[Leaf]

case class OriginalLeaf(id: String, val: Int)
type OriginalTree = Tree[OriginalLeaf]
```

And now your example becomes:

```
def update(tree: OriginalTree, id: String, val: Int): OriginalTree = tree.map {
  case OriginalLeaf(oldId, _) if oldId == id => OriginalLeaf(id, val)
  case anyOtherLeaf                          => anyOtherLeaf
}
```

If writing out the cases for different node types even once is troublesome, you can use [Kittens](https://github.com/typelevel/kittens) to derive the `Functor` instance [automatically](https://github.com/typelevel/kittens#derive-functor):

```
implicit val functorForTree: Functor[Tree] = {
  import cats.derived._
  import auto.functor._
  semi.functor
}
```